# Python ctypes calling reboot() from libc on Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, ctypes, libc

I'm trying to call the `reboot` function from libc in Python via `ctypes` and I just can not get it to work.  I've been referencing the `man 2 reboot` page (http://linux.die.net/man/2/reboot). My kernel version is 2.6.35.

Below is the console log from the interactive Python prompt where I'm trying to get my machine to reboot- what am I doing wrong?

Why isn't `ctypes.get_errno()` working?

```
>>> from ctypes import CDLL, get_errno
>>> libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')
>>> libc.reboot(0xfee1dead, 537993216, 0x1234567, 0)
-1
>>> get_errno()
0
>>> libc.reboot(0xfee1dead, 537993216, 0x1234567)
-1
>>> get_errno()
0
>>> from ctypes import c_uint32
>>> libc.reboot(c_uint32(0xfee1dead), c_uint32(672274793), c_uint32(0x1234567), c_uint32(0))
-1
>>> get_errno()
0
>>> libc.reboot(c_uint32(0xfee1dead), c_uint32(672274793), c_uint32(0x1234567))
-1
>>> get_errno()
0
>>>
```

**Edit:**

Via [Nemos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/768469/nemo) reminder- I can get `get_errno` to return 22 (invalid argument).  Not a surprise.  How should I be calling `reboot()`? I'm clearly not passing arguments the function expects. =)

Comment: Are you root when running this script?

Comment: access denied? I don't know... try (re)reading this: http://linux.die.net/man/2/reboot

Comment: Even if access were denied, one would expect `errno` to report `EPERM`.

Comment: yes, I'm root before starting the python interactive prompt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> libc = CDLL('libc.so.6', use_errno=True)
```

That should allow `get_errno()` to work.

[update]

Also, the last argument is a `void *`.  If this is a 64-bit system, then the integer 0 is not a valid repesentation for NULL.  I would try `None` or maybe `c_void_p(None)`.  (Not sure how that could matter in this context, though.)

[update 2]

Apparently `reboot(0x1234567)` does the trick (see comments).

Comment: trying `libc.reboot(0xfee1dead, 672274793, 0x1234567, c_void_p(None))` still returns errno 22. thanks for the idea though. (so does trying to use `c_uint()` around the args)

Comment: Have you tried just `reboot(0x1234567)`?  That's the signature I see in sys/reboot.h...

Comment: I thought I had, but I guess not- that seems to do the trick. Maybe update the answer?

Answer (score 3):

The `reboot()` in `libc` is a wrapper around the syscall, which only takes the `cmd` argument.  So try:

```
libc.reboot(0x1234567)
```

Note that you should normally be initiating a reboot by sending `SIGINT` to PID 1 - telling the kernel to reboot will not give any system daemons the chance to shut down cleanly, and won't even sync the filesystem cache to disk.